# Use Import Maps and Stimulus with Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I'm currently on Rails 6.0.4 and I want to use Stimulus to build a new page. There's a lot of work still to do before upgrading to Rails 7, so I want to use importmaps and stimulus with Rails 6 if possible. But so far I haven't been able to get a stimulus controller working. I followed these steps:

#### **1. Update the Gemfile and bundle:**

```
gem 'importmap-rails'
gem 'stimulus-rails'
```

#### **2. Run `rails importmap:install`**

This gave me `config/importmap.rb`, and `app/javascript/application.js`, which was pinned as "application" in the config file.

#### **3. Rename the current `application.js` file**

My current `application.js` is inside `app/assets/application.js.coffee`, so I renamed this to `old_application.js.coffee` for the time being and updated `application.html.haml` to the following:

```
= javascript_include_tag "old_application", defer: true
= javascript_importmap_tags
```

This seemed to work and it gave me the following import map when I rendered the page:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-920fceca960b509c1e98c9b27d167fa368d4b588ceb1be42d1667552714f94d5.js"
  }
}
```

#### **4.Run `rails stimulus:install`**

This gave me the `app/javascript/controllers` folder with `index.js`, `application.js` and `hello_controller.js` inside.

It also updated `config/importmap.rb` to the following:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

... and my `app/javascript/application.js` to the following:

```
import "controllers"
```

---

This then gives me an error, saying that `controllers/hello_controller.js` has not been precompiled:

[image: AssetNotPrecompiled Error]

#### **5. Update asset paths and precompiled files**

We're on version 3 of sprockets, and upgrading to version 4 will also take some time, due to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/273). So instead I updated the existing `initializers/assets.rb` file to include the new javascript folder and files:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'javascript', 'controllers')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['application.js', 'controllers/index.js', 'controllers/application.js', 'controllers/hello_controller.js']
```

This fixed the issue and gives me the following import map on the rendered page:

```
{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-920fceca960b509c1e98c9b27d167fa368d4b588ceb1be42d1667552714f94d5.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-c5a29ae8ade968ede2149a7e76a29d0756a87cef66959113681098e5923ba26b.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-6b29b7e0382bd421ac62df99b46f45072fd3962208fbf0b2522041b4d037bbd9.js",
    "controllers/hello_controller": "/assets/hello_controller-8cddac086717993eeda2cc8af3be73bc3a6ecfb07212600aeed8ce8122fffa34.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/index-7445df4dc00776a5e3496034da4bc5906891c342c89c0e6a7775b1498b8222d8.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/application-5703baa647baaa5a3da21d4e61aa5686824d0e0ab82c2ba11f5c963cc8414a8f.js"
  }
}
```

#### **6. Test stimulus controller with an alert**

I changed `hello_controller.js` to show an alert when it's connected:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    alert('Hello World!')
  }
}
```

But when I attach this to an element with `data-controller="hello"` I don't see anything, suggesting that stimulus hasn't been correctly loaded.

This is the partial for that:

```
.home-container{data: { controller: 'hello' }}
  %section
    .container
```

Which gives me this HTML:

```
<div class="home-container" data-controller="hello">
  <section>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </section>
<div>
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be missing? If I start a new rails app on Rails 7 and set everything up like that, it works without a problem.

Comment: Can you share the view or partial with the data-controller='hello' to the question?

Comment: @JoeThor yes I've updated the post with that partial, and the HTML it generates. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing the same issue. Running `rails assets:clean` and `rails assets:clobber` solved the issue for me. Sorry, I do not remember which one did the trick, as I was applying the clueless dog approach.